# LINQ union query with test for null on either component

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a union query in LINQ to combine the results of 2 other LINQ queries. The problem is either query might return a null dataset which throws the nullexception error. I've tried nesting an if statement in the query definition but I'm still getting the null exception (I realize this only tests for null on one of the queries but first things first):

```
 Dim DLFull = If(DLDFDetails Is Nothing, _
                    (From Data In DLDetails _
                 Select Data.Site, _
                        Data.Service_Name), _
                 (From Data In DLDetails _
                 Select Data.Site, _
                        Data.Service_Name) _
                 .Union _
                 (From DFData In DLDFDetails _
                 Select DFData.Site, _
                        DFData.Service_Name))
```

Any ideas how can I get around this? Thanks!

Comment: The result of a LINQ query shouldn't be NULL/Nothing unless you were trying to retrieve a specific record using something like find or single.  Otherwise it should be an empty dbset/enumerable which is quite different and shouldn't cause a problem with UNION.

Comment: OP means that queriable dataset may be null, not the query result

Comment: Do either of you have any ideas how I can work around this? When I try to test the queries individually for null it doesn't catch.

Comment: I may not be grasping this directly, but if there is a potential for either of the datasets (DLDFDetails or DLDetails) to be null, shouldn't you be doing that checking before you attempt to select from a null dataset?  In the case of either of them being null, you wouldn't attempt the Union, and you'd just return the non-null dataset.  Sorry if this is not applicable.